# What to do if my post is missing?

Tags: support, questions

I'd posted something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290761/java-ee-vs-javafx), but it seems missing now! Is it deleted?

I'm pretty sure that I had asked a question because the system has given me a badge for doing so!

What should I do to locate it?

Comment: Your post was [closed as not constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) and then deleted. This happened two days ago.

Comment: "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." yeah I see... At least can I get the text back so that I can post it somewhere else? or is it deleted completely?

Comment: I sent your deleted question (plus the one answer) to your gmail account.

Comment: It should be noted that the question would *still* be closed under "not a real question"; it asks *three* questions which should really be three *separate* questions.  Having three questions on one page fits the definition of NARQ - "it is difficult to tell what is being asked here." I'd suggest breaking it out into individual questions and **fleshing them out** and they will probably all be better received (assuming they still fit the criteria for good questions on SO).

Comment: @casperOne: Edit and emphasize "fleshing them out" as just breaking that question apart will result in four closed and deleted questions instead of just one.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't: Done.  You could have edited the comment though, I see a diamond thingy on you too. =)

Comment: @casperOne: Give a man a fish, and he eats for a day.  Harass a new mod, and he'll hate you forever.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't I like where you're going with that.

Comment: @JayRiggs I didn't receive the text... I received the answers though. Sorry for being a bother, but can you send the text to me (again)?

Comment: I sent it again.  Not sure why the first one didn't work.  If this one doesn't work feel free to email me and I'll reply (my email is in my SO profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been deleted for not being of a good format for SO, like too subjective or something (see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)).

10k users can still see deleted posts and vote to "undelete" it if it is justified. Maybe they'll do it thanks to this question, maybe not.